# Bevy Add background image with sprite animation

Tags: rust, bevy

I'm using bevy adding two Spawn lawyers.
One is the background and the other is the sprite I want to animate.

For some reason I can only see the background image but not the sprite.

```
use bevy::prelude::*;
use bevy::render::render_resource::Texture;

fn main() {
    App::new()
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins.set(ImagePlugin::default_nearest())) // prevents blurry sprites
        .add_systems(Startup, setup)
        .add_systems(Update, animate_sprite)
        .run();
}

#[derive(Component)]
struct AnimationIndices {
    // running_right:bool,
    first: usize,
    last: usize,
}

#[derive(Component, Deref, DerefMut)]
struct AnimationTimer(Timer);

fn animate_sprite(
    time: Res<Time>,
    keyboard_input: Res<Input<KeyCode>>,
    mut query: Query<(
        &AnimationIndices,
        &mut AnimationTimer,
        &mut TextureAtlasSprite,
        &mut Transform,
    )>,
) {
    for (indices, mut timer, mut sprite, mut transform) in &mut query {
        timer.tick(time.delta());
        if timer.just_finished() {
            if keyboard_input.pressed(KeyCode::Right) {
                sprite.flip_x=false;
                info!("'Right' currently pressed");
                sprite.index = if sprite.index == indices.last {
                    indices.first
                } else {
                    sprite.index + 1
                };
                // Move the sprite to the right
                transform.translation.x += 10.0; // Adjust the movement speed as needed
            }
            if keyboard_input.pressed(KeyCode::Left) {
                sprite.flip_x=true;
                info!("'Right' currently pressed");
                sprite.index = if sprite.index == indices.last {
                    indices.first
                } else {
                    sprite.index + 1
                };
                // Move the sprite to the left
                transform.translation.x -= 10.0; // Adjust the movement speed as needed
            }
        }
    }
}

fn setup(
    mut commands: Commands,
    asset_server: Res<AssetServer>,
    mut texture_atlases: ResMut<Assets<TextureAtlas>>,
) {
    let background_image = asset_server.load("namek.png");
    let texture_handle = asset_server.load("gabe-idle-run.png");
    let texture_atlas =
        TextureAtlas::from_grid(texture_handle, Vec2::new(24.0, 24.0), 7, 1, None, None);
    let texture_atlas_handle = texture_atlases.add(texture_atlas);
    // Use only the subset of sprites in the sheet that make up the run animation
    let animation_indices = AnimationIndices { first: 1, last: 6 };
    commands.spawn(Camera2dBundle::default());
    commands.spawn(SpriteBundle {
        texture: background_image,
        // sprite: Sprite::default(),
        // sprite: Sprite::new(Vec2::new(1920.0, 1080.0)), // Adjust dimensions as needed
        // transform: Transform::from_translation(Vec3::new(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)), // Adjust position as needed
        ..default()
    }).with_children(|parent|{
        parent.spawn((
            SpriteSheetBundle {
                texture_atlas: texture_atlas_handle,
                sprite: TextureAtlasSprite::new(animation_indices.first),
                transform: Transform::from_scale(Vec3::splat(6.0)),
                ..default()
            },
            animation_indices,
            AnimationTimer(Timer::from_seconds(0.1, TimerMode::Repeating)),
        ));
    });
}
```

If I comment the background spawn and I leave only the sprite, it's working fine.

Any ideas, I cannot find a good documentation about this.